# Read data in Excel column into Python list

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using python xlwings to read a column of data in Excel 2013. Column `A` is populated with numbers. To import this column into a python list `py_list`, I have the following code;

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('BookName.xlsm')
sht = xw.Book('SheetName')
py_list = sht.range('A2:A40').value
```

The above code works if the column data is populated at `A2:A40`. However, the column data can keep growing. Data can grow and stretch to `A2:A46` or `A2:A80`. The last row is empty. It is not known at compile time how many rows of data is in this column.

How can I modify the code to detect the empty cell at the last row so that the range of data can be read by `py_list`?

I am open to using other python libraries to read the Excel data besides xlwings. I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I say this a lot about reading files in from csv or excel, but I would use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsm', sheetname=0) # can also index sheet by name or fetch all sheets
mylist = df['column name'].tolist()
```

an alternative would be to use a dynamic formula using soemthing like OFFSET in excel instead of `'A2:A40'`, or perhaps a named range?

Comment: If the sheetname is `SheetName`, how can I modify your code? Is this correct? `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsm', sheetname='SheetName') `

Comment: that looks right to me, details on the function are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Your answer will work on excel files which are not password-protected. Unfortunately, my excel file is password-protected. Nevertheless, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @stael If i wanted to read multiple excel files in a loop and put a the same column in each file in a list.  How would i append to the list in each pass?

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but you can also use  [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("BookName.xlsx")  # Work Book
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SheetName')  # Work Sheet
column = ws['A']  # Column
column_list = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]
```

Notes:

- [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is an awesome library, but installing it just to read an excel column into a list is an overkill IMHO.
- [*xlrd*](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) is not maintained anymore. From the [xlrd github page](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd)

  > PLEASE NOTE: This library currently has no active maintainers. You are advised to use OpenPyXL instead.

Comment: get_sheet_by_name has a deprecation warning.  Use ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[x]], where x is the element of a list representing the name of the sheet you want.  You must use wb[wb.sheetnames[x]] since this returns an object (a Worksheet) that you can then iterate through using column = ws['A'], you cannot use ws = wb.sheetnames[0], which returns a str object

Answer (score 4):

I found this as the easiest way to create lists from the entire columns in excel and it only takes the populated excel cells. 
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
#Insert complete path to the excel file and index of the worksheet
df = pd.read_excel("PATH.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
# insert the name of the column as a string in brackets
list1 = list(df['Column Header 1']) 
list2 = list(df['Column Header 2'])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I went through xlwings documentation to look for something, didn't find something like this, but you can always try and go around this:

```
temp = [x for x in xw.Range('A2:A200').value if x != None] #A200 just put a big number..
```

or I don't know try this:

```
from itertools import takewhile
temp =[takewhile(lambda x: x != None, xw.Range('A2:A70').value)]
while True:
    try:
         next(temp)
    except StopIteration:
         break
```

at line 2, at first I tried doing something like this:

```
temp =[lambda x: x for x in xw.Range('D:D').values if x != None else exit()] #or to replace this with quit() but there is no option to break lambdas as far as I know
```

another option:

```
temp = iter(xw.Range('A:A').value)
list = []
a = next(temp)               #depending your first cell starts at row 1
while a != None:             #might want zeros or '' etc
    list.append(a)
    a = next(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to this question is finding out the number of rows in column `A`.

The number of rows can be found with this single line using xlwings below;

```
rownum = sht.range('A1').end('down').last_cell.row
```

One needs to read the API documentation carefully to get the answer.

http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range

Once the number of rows is found, it is easy to figure out the rest.