# How to read the excel column as list using python?

Tags: python, excel

How to read the excel column  as list using python?

Excel data: Input File(input.xlsx)

```
Column1      Column2  Column3  Column4 
one          two      three    four    
22/03/1997   six      7        eight
```

code

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("input.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

col = []

for i in range(1,sheet.nrows):
  col.append(str(sheet.row_values(i)))
```

But my code will print in row wise but i want to read data in column wise

Expected Output:

```
[[Column1,one,22/03/1997],[Column2,two,six],[Column3,three,7,],[ Column4,four,eight]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708626/read-data-in-excel-column-into-python-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("input.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
col = []
for i in range(0,sheet.ncols):
    col.append(str(sheet.col_values(i)))
print col
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=None)
result = [list(df[x].values) for x in df.columns.values]
```

Output:

```
[['Column1', 'one', '22/03/1997'], ['Column2', 'two', 'six'], ['Column3', 'three', 7], ['Column4', 'four', 'eight']]
```